# Filtering results based on date and fetching one previous value

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IDbSet` which I am querying as following:

```
var list = MessageSet.Where(x => x.Date >= fromDate && x.Date <= toDate);
```

Later on I do other LINQ queries such as `Select`, `OrderBy` and so on.

In order to calculate and transform the data in the way I want, I also need the last value before `fromDate`, which I can obtain as:

```
var prevValue = MessageSet.Where(x => x.Date < fromDate).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, I am doing a `Join` with another `IQueryable`, so this is not really working for me

Is there a way to combine those queries?

Comment: have you tried `Union` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do an union to get all entries between your dates and the one before?

```
var list = MessageSet.Where(x => x.Date >= fromDate && x.Date <= toDate)
                     .Union(MessageSet
                            .Where(x=>x.Date < fromDate).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).Take(1)
    );
```